# How to get CORRECT feature importance plot in XGBOOST?

Tags: python, xgboost

Using two different methods in XGBOOST feature importance, gives me two different most important features, which one should be believed?

Which method should be used when? I am confused.

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
import xgboost as xgb

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
df = df.drop(['name','origin'],axis=1)

X = df.iloc[:,1:]
y = df.iloc[:,0]
```

## Numpy arrays

```py
# fit the model
model_xgb_numpy = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_jobs=-1,objective='reg:squarederror')
model_xgb_numpy.fit(X.to_numpy(), y.to_numpy())

plt.bar(range(len(model_xgb_numpy.feature_importances_)), model_xgb_numpy.feature_importances_)
```

[image]

## Pandas dataframe

```py
# fit the model
model_xgb_pandas = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_jobs=-1,objective='reg:squarederror')
model_xgb_pandas.fit(X, y)
axsub = xgb.plot_importance(model_xgb_pandas)
```

[image]

## Problem

Numpy method shows 0th feature cylinder is most important. Pandas method shows model year is most important. Which one is the CORRECT most important feature?

## References

- [How to get feature importance in xgboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627923/how-to-get-feature-importance-in-xgboost)
- [Feature importance 'gain' in XGBoost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360703/feature-importance-gain-in-xgboost)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to define THE correct feature importance measure. Each has pros and cons. It is a wide topic with no golden rule as of now and I personally would suggest to read this online book by Christoph Molnar: https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/. The book has an excellent overview of different measures and different algorithms.

As a rule of thumb, if you can not use an external package, i would choose `gain`, as it is more representative of what one is interested in (one typically is not interested in raw occurrence of splits on a particular features, but rather how much those splits helped), see this question for a good summary: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12318/53060. If you can use other tools, [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) exhibits very good behaviour and I would **always** choose it over build-in xgb tree measures, unless computation time is strongly constrained.

As for the difference that you directly pointed at in your question, the root of the difference comes from the fact that `xgb.plot_importance` uses `weight` as the default extracted feature importance type, while the `XGBModel` itself uses `gain` as the default type. If you configure them to use the same importance type, then you will get similar distributions (up to additional normalisation in `feature_importance_` and sorting in `plot_importance`).

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 ways to get feature importance from Xgboost:

- use built-in feature importance (I prefer `gain` type),
- use permutation-based feature importance
- use SHAP values to compute feature importance

In my [post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) I wrote code examples for all 3 methods. Personally, I'm using permutation-based feature importance. In my opinion, the built-in feature importance can show features as important after overfitting to the data(this is just an opinion based on my experience). SHAP explanations are fantastic, but sometimes computing them can be time-consuming (and you need to downsample your data).

Answer (score 3):

From [the answer here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/41548/65752), which gives a neat explanation:

`feature_importances_` returns weights - what we usually think of as "importance".

`plot_importance` returns the number of occurrences in splits.

Note: I think that the selected answer above does not actually cover the point.